# How can i upload multiple files for my existing project using carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, multiple-file-upload

here is the attachment code in my _form.html.erb

```
<div class="control-group">
      <%= f.label :attachment , :class => 'control-label' %>
      <div class="controls">
        <%= f.file_field :attachment, :class => 'file_field', multiple: 'true' %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

here is my model invoice_details.rb

```
class InvoiceDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount_uploader :attachment, AttachmentUploader
  #validates :invoice_number, :supplier_name, :attachment, presence: true # Make sure the owner's name is present.    
  #validates_uniqueness_of :invoice_number
 #validates :invoice_number, length: { maximum: 7 }
 #validates :supplier_name, length: { maximum: 20 }
 #validates :description_of_goods, length: { maximum: 50 }
 #validates :quatity, numericality: true
 #validates :price_per_unit, numericality: true
 #validates :total_amount, numericality: true
end
```

here another model invoice_file.rb

```
class InvoiceFile < ActiveRecord::Base
mount_uploader :attachment, AttachmentUploader # Tells rails to use this uploader for this model.
  validates :name, presence: true # Make sure the owner's name is present.  
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add dynamic nested fields in your form with file field input, but it is bad solution, because in that way you can get in trouble with timeout when someone will try to upload eg. 20 files at once.

I think the easitest and fastest solution will be to use the 'jquery-fileupload-rails' gem. Please check the source code of demo app and adjust it to your application.

Here is an nice example: 
https://github.com/n0ne/Rails-Carrierwave-jQuery-File-Upload